# How do I beat the Adamantite Shell?

Tags: bravely-default-demo

In the *Bravely Default* demo there is a quest to defeat the rock-like monster in the forest. It is an Adamantite Shell with a high defense and the ability to cast reflect.

<del>I've figured out how to get around the `Reflect` spell. `Reflect` only bounces one spell back so if I cast cure or some beneficial magic it will get bounced back to me, and I can hit it with `Blizzard` (or another water spell) in the next round.</del>

But the problem here is that it has 3000 HP and a very high defense. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Clever trick getting rid of his Reflect like that! I simply didn't use spells, but your way is better.

Comment: Very cool. Reflect ability - I would just Default through it and wait for it to fall off while keeping my team up, but that is way better.

Comment: No, I was wrong about reflect. It only came off after it did the special attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to have 3 Black Mages and 1 White Mage. Since it had such a high physical defense I just ignored that avenue. I braved until it went for it's attack, then I spent the points on a massive round of `Blizzard` × 2 or 3 and lots of healing. This way I kept my HP mostly stable as I continued to chip away at it when it couldn't attack me. Rinse and repeat until it died.

Answer (score 2):

I stuck with my start group of Knight, Ninja, Valkyrie, Swordmaster. All level 8, job 3.

It takes a bunch of time.

I had decent gear but nothing but the default weapons.

All had the Bushido subclass for Nothing Ventured. It did 30-50 damage each time he used his Shell Spike PER PERSON. (Minus the Ninja. Ninja I had subkitted with B/W Magic, will explain)

The Ninja used Utsusemi to mitigate damage and gain spell power with Comeback Kid.

Brave when he braves and keep an eye on his BP.

He usually attacks at 0 or at 2.

When Reflect is down, have the Ninja fully stacked with brave unload some Blizzard.

Heal when he's in the negative BP's.

It takes some time but it isn't that hard. Just gotta outsmart the poor thing.

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a way "around" his high defense and HP, no.

Unfortunately I suspect you'll want to grind for some more levels and money to have better stats, more abilities, and buy better equipment.

Equipment in particular seems to matter a lot in this game - lousy equipment will do piddling damage against enemies with high defense. but good equipment seems to manage.

Fortunately, grinding is not hard to do and can be sped up a whole lot. My recommendation would be to go somewhere you can rock the enemies with just Attacks - like out in the desert or the first dungeon. Equip a Taunt accessory (sold in town) and walk around to get in a fight. Use Brave 3 times and Attack 4 time with all characters, then press Y to enable Auto mode - this will cause all characters to keep doing that same thing until you disable Auto mode (by pressing Y again). While everyone is fighting, press DPad right twice to go into full Fast Forward, making battles go by in a flash.

With this setup in place, you should be able to walk around and destroy enemies in short order, gaining XP and cash in a hurry. Just make sure you go to the Inn when you get low on health, and de-equip the Taunt accessory and disable Auto mode before you go back into the forest.

Once you are equipped to the gills with sweet swords and better Abilities, go show that boss who's... boss.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I defeated it so I might be missing some points, but as far as I remember, I beat it through the following, in addition to what you've mentioned about reflecting cure:

- Default when it's attacking to minimize damage. I noticed it rarely attacked with single BP.
- Default/cure when it's defaulting. Attacking when damage it would incur is reduced could be saved by stocking up BP.
- Attacking with every member once it launched its most powerful attack. It will all into negative BP and won't be able to attack, defend or heal during this lapse of time.

Try to keep all your members at full health and you can attack with basic attacks if you have full BP and the Tortoise is defaulting. Some damage is better than no damage.

Keep doing damage, and you'll get at it eventually. Of course, try to get the best gears, and some recovery items are welcome too.

Classes I found useful:

- Valkyrie class - Can dodge the strongest move via jumping and counter strongly. Has also high defenses
- Red Mage class - Access to both Black and White magic is pretty nice, plus the effective water damage seemed reasonable to me.
- White/Black Mage class - Major damage, or great recovery, pick what you think suits you best.
- Knight class - Just to endure all those hard hits and still deliver decent damage

I *think* I beat it with my characters at around level 12/13.

Comment: How does a Valkyrie counter?

Comment: @CyberSkull 'counter' might not have been the best wording here, I admit. It's more like it can attack right after the opponent attacked, a time where it is the most vulnerable.

Comment: Black Mage Damage Dispersal, and White Mage angelic grace also helps to neutralize damage on Agnis if you have her going mage.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to defeat the turtle using an all black mage team.

Keep one with white magic for heals, the other abilities don't matter too much. For passives, the damage dispersion passive from black mages helps a lot plus the white mage passive that reduces damage.

Just Default until you're maxed out and then continue to default (and probably heal) until his reflect shield wears off and then blast him with blizzard. I did a 4x brave for each character (at +3 BP you only end up at -1 so you only have a one turn vulnerability)

Answer (score 0):

Well... from my experience, the battle requires patience above all if you're around lvl 10~11 during the time of the battle.

Easiest way to beat it would be to use a all black mage team since u get the dmg multiplier. If you can, take a lvl 3+ red/white mage and a lvl 3+ knight as the black mage's subjob. The knight can block the dmg of the healer using full cover while the healer spam brave+cure on team to heal up after deadly attacks.

Also, keep track of the turtle's BP. If you default enough, you can usually keep a BP of around 3 for all your characters except for the healer (since he/she is using up all their turn to heal).

Really, all the battle takes is a lot of patience since it take time to set up, heal, deal damage and all that other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Have atleast one black mage/red mage that can use blizzard or blizzara...it's weakness

Answer (score 0):

When I did this I made all my people black mages and maxed out my braves and then put them all to blizzard. And when my people got low I gave them all a potion.i guess I got lucky because I was able to do this every turn and the turtle never used the reflection magic